# How to bypass header from request into header in response in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have API Gateway endpoint, which is actually mock endpoint.
What I am trying to do is to make API to take Origin header from request and return the same value in response as Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

So far I've tried to do the following:

- Got to "Method Request" and add "Origin" header to the list
- In "Method Execution" I am trying to map Access-Control-Allow-Origin to method.request.header.Origin, but I am getting an error message
  `Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: method.request.header.Origin]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

integration.request and integration.response only prepare the input to and output from the integration response. Therefore the integration request only supports additional input from the method.request and the integration response only supports additional input from the method response definitions.

Mapping the method.request parameters to method.response is currently not supported but definitely a valid and useful use case. I'll add it to our backlog, but unfortunately cannot commit to a timeline for when we plan on delivering this feature enhancement.

As a workaround, you could pass the Origin header to your integration endpoint which simply mirrors the input and passes it back to API Gateway. This way you should be able to return the value of the Origin request header as an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

Hope this helps,

Jurgen, API Gateway

Comment: You've answered faster than AWS support!:) Thanks Jurgen!

Comment: any update on this @Jurgen ? This is especially important for CORS requests.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by [input.param](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference) and [context.responseOvverride](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference) methods

In Integration Response add a Mapping Template for proper Content-Type with a body like this:

```
#set($origin = $input.params('origin')) 
#set($context.responseOverride.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin = $origin)
```

It should look like this:
[image]

Of course, it can also be added via Cloud Formation and [x-amazon-apigateway-integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html). Example part of yaml:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  responses:
    default:
      statusCode: "200"
      responseTemplates:
        application/json: |
          #set($origin = $input.params('origin')) 
          #set($context.responseOverride.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin = $origin)
```

Hope that helps.